# (AWS) Terraform: "no matching Route53Zone found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-api-gateway

Im currently trying to set up an AWS EC2 Instance & integrated API-Gateway with terraform.
I watched the tutorial of Anton Putra: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XhS2JbPg8jA&t=287s
and also cloned his code: https://github.com/antonputra/tutorials/tree/main/lessons/118

I simply wanted to rename some of the resources and apply the terraform.
"terraform init" works but when i run "terraform apply", i get this message:
[CMD Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgorZ.png)

This is the code from the file its complaining about:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "gradebook" {
    domain_name          = "gradebook.bmeisn.com"
    validation_method = "DNS"
} 

data "aws_route53_zone" "gradebook-r53z" {
    name              = "bmeisn.com"
    private_zone      = false
} 

resource "aws_route53_record" "gradebook-r53r" {
    for_each = {
        for dvo in aws_acm_certificate.gradebook.domain_validation_options : dvo.domain_name => {
            name    = dvo.resource_record_name
            record    = dvo.resource_record_value
            type    = dvo.resource_record_type
        }
    }     
    allow_overwrite = true
    name            = each.value.name
    records            = [each.value.record]
    ttl                = 60
    type            = each.value.type
    zone_id            = data.aws_route53_zone.gradebook-r53z.zone_id
} 

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "gradebook" {
    certificate_arn            = aws_acm_certificate.gradebook.arn
    validation_record_fqdns    = [for record in aws_route53_record.gradebook-r53r : record.fqdn ]
}
```

I read that it might be because of the domain so heres the tf file for that aswell:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name" "gradebook" {
  domain_name = "gradebook.bmeisn.com"   domain_name_configuration {
    certificate_arn = aws_acm_certificate.gradebook.arn
    endpoint_type   = "REGIONAL"
    security_policy = "TLS_1_2"
  }   
depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate_validation.gradebook]
} 
resource "aws_route53_record" "gradebook-r53r-02" {
  name    = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.gradebook.domain_name
  type    = "A"
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.gradebook-r53z.zone_id   alias {
    name                   = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.gradebook.domain_name_configuration[0].target_domain_name
    zone_id                = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.gradebook.domain_name_configuration[0].hosted_zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
} 
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_api_mapping" "gradebook-map" {
  api_id      = aws_apigatewayv2_api.gradebook-agw.id
  domain_name = aws_apigatewayv2_domain_name.gradebook.id
  stage       = aws_apigatewayv2_stage.dev.id
} 
output "custom_domain_api-v2" {
  value = "https://${aws_apigatewayv2_api_mapping.gradebook-map.domain_name}/health"
}
```

The whole setup around it seems to work so im assuming i did something wrong here, i just cant figure out what exactly as im not very experienced with this technology.

Also if this question is missing any important info, let me know.

Comment: Have you registered that domain in Route53?

Comment: Im not exactly sure, how do i do that? @MarkoE

Comment: Well, you can't simply use a domain someone else had registered, you have to have one yourself. As for how you do it, there is plenty documentation which can guide ypu through the required steps. Note that registering a domain comes with a cost.

Comment: am i not creating the domain with this tf file? @MarkoE

Comment: You are not. You are using a data source to get details about an existing domain, and then trying to create a record in that domain.

Comment: Any TF resource that has a prefix of `data` is doing a lookup, rather than creating so it’s managed outside of TF and must already exist. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you aren't exactly creating your Route 53 zone. If you're committed to do it via Terraform (I'd personally advise against it but it's your choice to make) [`aws_route53_zone`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/route53_zone) resource is what you seek, it also has example on how to reference a zone you're to create.
In case you still get messages about it being absent AFTER referencing *zone resource you are creating* (Terraform borking the resource creating order), then just use [`depends_on`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) and call it a day.